# MongoDB how to save specific arrayelements or "refer" to an element?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following structure (this can't be changed, that is I have to work with):

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("abc123"),
        "notreallyusedfields" : "dontcare",
        "data" : [
                {
                        "value" : "Demian",
                        "otherSomtimesInterestingFields": 1
                        "type" : title,
                },
                {
                        "value" : "200",
                        "otherSometimesInterestingFields": 1
                        "type" : length,
                },
                {
                        "value" : "Hesse",
                        "otherSometimesInterestingFields": 1
                        "type" : author,
                },
                many others
        ]
}
```

I'd like to save data array elements (based on "type") or somehow refer to them but I don't know how. Not every data array has the same kind of elements (sometimes for example author is missing and so on). If that was the case and the order is guaranteed I could use arrayElementAt operator like this:

```
$project:
  {

     title: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$data", 0 ] },
     length: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$data", 1 ] },
     author: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$data", 2 ] },

  }
```

How could you do something like this with the given structure?

I need this because the structure I have is basically the fields are inside the data array for a given schema and I can't really use join or grouping where I can't tell which "field" (which element of the data array) to be grouped by or joined by. That is why I think the desired element should be "saved" with a name somehow so I can refer to them.

I can bypass the problem by using java and doing the stuff there (like I did it with the join problem) but it is getting uglier if I keep solving these problembs in JAVA instead of mongoDB.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`$filter`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) aggregation to find the specific `type` inside the `data` array and then can use [**`$arrayELemAt`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) with the filtered array

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "title": {
      "$arrayElemAt": [
        { "$filter": { "input": "$data", "cond": { "$eq": ["$$this.type", "title"] }}},
        0
      ]
    },
    "length": {
      "$arrayElemAt": [
        { "$filter": { "input": "$data", "cond": { "$eq": ["$$this.type", "length"] }}},
        0
      ]
    },
    "author": {
      "$arrayElemAt": [
        { "$filter": { "input": "$data", "cond": { "$eq": ["$$this.type", "author"] }}},
        0
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```